# Why does my app restart, even though it is already running and should just switch focus?

Tags: applications

When I open a special company-internal app I need for work through my gesture-controlled overlay menu, it sometimes completely restarts, even though it's already open in the background. What's the reason for this and how can I stop it?

Comment: Only the developer of the app can answer this question. There's no universal rule applicable to every app.

Answer (score 0):

After days of fiddling and googling I finally noticed that it depends on where the app is **initially** started from (meaning the first start from when it has been closed before).

- If I initially start it from the overlay, I can switch to it via overlay without it
  restarting, but it restarts when using the normal home screen button.
- If I initially start it from the home screen, it's the other way around (works from home screen, restarts from overlay).

Comment: I will say but one thing: Lifecycle - [Understand the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). Well, two things: [Understanding Context In Android Application](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514). Also, App Development is off-topic here, there are stackexchanges devoted to app development.

Comment: @wbogacz I'm a user, not a developer, so I'm pretty sure the question is fine here? Whatever just wanted to help people out if anyone ever has the same problem, no need to overcomplicate.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "overlay"? Is it an always-on draw-over-apps type? Or is it from the "app switcher" button?

Comment: @AndrewT. First one. I ended up using UbikiTouch because I like it best, but I've tried many others as well. The behavior is reproducible in all that I tested it with.

Comment: @MaxD - Sorry about that. The read I took on the question is that you had developed the app for the company. For my company, any apps like this were limited distro, so group-effort and everybody knew the internal workings. I read too much into it.